# Windows 10 volume mixer remember my settings?

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

In Windows 10 volume mixer, I want to be able to set the "relative" volume for various apps, e.g. Spotify should always be about 25 % of the system sounds. I can set this manually of course, but I often find that the Spotify volume (for example) has been reset to 100 %. Not sure exactly when that happens, but could be that it happens when I switch between output devices, i.e. unplug the laptop from the docking station (with attached speakers) so it switches to the built in speakers, or vice versa.

How can I get the relative volume to persist properly?

Comment: I once had the same question, but when I searched on the internet, there were only solutions regarding volume randomly going up and down, This was caused by Audio Enhancements. However, this problem is different, windows doesn't remember what value we'd set the last time we used the app, and sets it back to 100, which is really irritating. But the solution to this isn't present anywhere.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I believe Windows does not have a way to set volume for an specific app. It has, however, a memory related to the output device. I often switch (by plugging and unplugging headphones) and they automatically adjust the volume to the value lastly set when using that output device.